# Error de Insersión de datos en Mysqli con Android Studio usando API PHP

Tags: android-studio, mysqli, api, guardar

Me encantaria que me ayudaran con el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de guardar datos en mysqli por medio de una API de PHP desde android studio. Al momento de presionar el boton de guardado, me dice que los datos han sido guardados pero al revisar la BD no hay ningún registro. Cuando programé el boton para que solo guardará funsionó despues de muchos intentos, pero al momento de agregar la opcion de modificar el registro existente con el mismo botón de guardado, la parte para guardar ya no funsiona sin embargo la de actualizar si. Les dejo el código del boton de guardado y de la api de guardar. Cualquier ayuda u opinion seria de gran ayuda, Gracias. Cabe mensionar que llevo menos de un año aprendiendo a programar.

````
``` public void GuardarFactura(View view){
        codFactura = jetCodVenta.getText().toString().trim();
        fechaFactura = jetFechaVenta.getText().toString().trim();
        userName = jetUsuarioVenta.getText().toString().trim();
        usrMoto = jetNombreUsrVenta.getText().toString().trim();
        usrComprador = jetNombreComprador.getText().toString().trim();
        moto = menuMotos.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().trim();
        refMoto = jtvRefMoto.getText().toString().trim();
        descMoto = jtvDescMoto.getText().toString().trim();
        valorMoto = jtvValorMoto.getText().toString().trim();
        if (codFactura.isEmpty() || fechaFactura.isEmpty() || userName.isEmpty() || 
            usrMoto.isEmpty() || usrComprador.isEmpty() || refMoto.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debe ingresar todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            jetCodVenta.requestFocus();
        } else {
            if(sw == 0) {
                url = "Http://192.168.1.15:80/WebServices/crearFactura.php";
                cap = 0;
            } else{
                url = "Http://192.168.1.15:80/WebServices/actualizarFact.php";
                cap = 1;
            }

            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            if(cap == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Factura guardada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                sw = 0;
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Factura actualizada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                sw = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            if ( cap == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error guardando factura!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error actualizando factura!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("codfactura", codFactura);
                    params.put("fechafactura", fechaFactura);
                    params.put("codusr", userName);
                    params.put("nameusrfactura", usrMoto);
                    params.put("comprador", usrComprador);
                    params.put("moto", moto);
                    params.put("refmoto", refMoto);
                    params.put("descmoto", descMoto);
                    params.put("valormoto", valorMoto);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(postRequest);
        }
    } ```

La API para guardar:

``` <?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['codfactura']) && isset($_REQUEST['fechafactura']) && isset($_REQUEST['codusr']) && isset($_REQUEST['nameusrfactura']) && isset($_REQUEST['comprador']) && isset($_REQUEST['moto']) && isset($_REQUEST['refmoto']) && isset($_REQUEST['descmoto']) && isset($_REQUEST['valormoto']))
{
    $codfactura=$_REQUEST['codfactura'];
    $fechafactura=$_REQUEST['fechafactura'];
    $codusr=$_REQUEST['codusr'];
    $nameusrfactura=$_REQUEST['nameusrfactura'];
    $comprador=$_REQUEST['comprador'];
    $moto=$_REQUEST['moto'];
    $refmoto=$_REQUEST['refmoto'];
    $descmoto=$_REQUEST['descmoto'];
    $valormoto=$_REQUEST['valormoto'];
    $cnx =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","empresa") or die(mysqli_error());
    $result = mysqli_query($cnx,"SELECT codfactura FROM ventas_moto WHERE codfactura='$codfactura'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
    {
        mysqli_query($cnx,"INSERT INTO ventas_moto (codfactura,fechafactura,codusr,nameusrfactura,comprador,moto,refmoto,descmoto,valormoto) VALUES ('$codfactura','$fechafactura','$codusr','$nameusrfactura','$comprador','$moto','$refmoto','$descmoto','$valormoto')");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ya existe la factura";
    }
    mysqli_close($cnx);
}
else
{
    echo "Debe especificar los datos para el registro";
}
?> ```
````

Comment: Prueba primero a ejecutar el PHP desde alguna aplicación de test, como por ejemplo Postman. Verifica que el PHP funciona y los errores que te devuelven. Dado que quieres trabajar con una API, intenta devolver respuestas estandar de una API rest para que te sea más sencillo trazar todo

Comment: Muchas gracias Jakala, me ha servido mucho utilizar postman. Me pude dar cuenta que el error estaba en la base de datos al utilizar el nombre de los vendedores como registros unicos, de esta manera no dejaba almancenar mas facturas con el mismo vendedor. No conocia postman, me ha servido mucho, de verdad gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al aporte de Jakala, pude encontrar el error en la base de datos utilizando Postman. En los parametros que recibia la base de datos, el nombre del vendedor se encontraba como registro unico, impidiendo registrar mas facturas a nombre de un mismo vendedor.

Duplicate entry '' for key 'unique_codusr'

En la ejeucicion del comando, la base de datos arrojaba un error de doble entrada en el nombre del vendedor, este error no esta contemplado en la API, solo si la API no recibe todos los parametros, si no se establece una conexion a la base de datos ó si se encuentra un registro con la misma clave primaria, por lo que al tratar de insertar los datos el resultado era "Regjstro guardado".

Para corregir el error solo le quité el privilegio de clave unica o "UNIQUE KEY" a la columna en la base de datos.